# cannot ping my computer on local network

Tags: networking, opensuse, ping

I am running on 64 bit **OpenSuSe 13.2** with Gnome 3 desktop environment and unsuccessfully trying to set up Samba Server. I have another computer running windows 8.1 from which I am pinging the ip address of my Linux machine. My firewall is disabled. What other factors could be blocking my linux machine?

I can successfully ping on my windows 8.1 from my linux machine though.

**Note** I have two routers (tp-link ASDL) and (netis). Sometimes I can ping and access local webserver of linux (apache) from windows 8.1 I am guessing this is due to slow connection problem.

Here is output of ifconfig of linux

```
nuke1:/home/santoshlinkha # ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F4:6D:04:56:9B:2B  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7368235 (7.0 Mb)  TX bytes:7368235 (7.0 Mb)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BC:77:37:AC:63:7C  
          inet6 addr: fe80::be77:37ff:feac:637c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:93117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:98142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:58302013 (55.6 Mb)  TX bytes:27770084 (26.4 Mb)
```

Here is output of my ipconfig in windows 8.1

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::edc2:243b:ad78:3b1d%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.108
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{87EDE97A-520D-44AA-B06B-9A89EDC96497}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:2833:cc04:8e38:2b5d
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2833:cc04:8e38:2b5d%11
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

[image]

Comment: What does wireshark say, when sending ICMP-Echo-Requests?

Comment: @ThomasJunk I haven't installed wire shark. I'll install it and let you know ... also do you mean it from win -> linux or linux -> win??

Comment: It will be useful to put additional information as :IP address, netmask and default gateway of each equipment.

Comment: @jcbermu updated

Comment: It seems to me, that your PC does not have a vailid IPv4 and IPv6 address for the local network. I guess your are using the LAN connection so please try to run `dhclient enp3s0` which will try to get a IP adress from the DHCP server (your router). Then have a look at `ifconfig` again.

Comment: That `ifconfig` output doesn't show any IPv4 addresses on either of your adapters. Are you using IPv6?

Comment: @Benjamin I got error `ls: cannot access /var/run/netconfig//enp3s0/: No such file or directory`

Comment: @AdityaK No .. I honestly don't know IPv6

Comment: @SantoshLinkha run it as root, via `sudo dhclient enp3s0`

Comment: @Benjamin I was logged in as `su` when I ran it, there might be problem in path `/var/run/netconfig//enp3s0/`

Comment: Making the assumption that you *want* an IPv4 address, is there any useful diagnostic information in /var/log/messages?

Comment: I think that the 2 machines are on different subnets. How they are connected to the two routers ?

Comment: @NIZ I connected both machines on same router (both of them).

Comment: Can you run cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases on the linux machine
(i dont know if opensuse use that exact file)

Comment: @NIZ it's empty

Comment: @AdityaK sorry I forgot to reply you ... I have no such file :-(

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Okay then please try reconfiguring your network using YaST

Comment: @Benjamin I tried to configure it using the info on [this site](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_yast.html) but I found that mine DHCP client option is disabled.

Comment: Seems Like you are using systemd's NetworkManager, try setting it to the legacy ifup method or configure NetworkManager acordingly. Maybe you could also try to configure a static IP.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha: If you have solved your problem, you should post an *answer* saying what you did.

Comment: @G-Man the best way would be to permanently change my ip address (IPv4), which I don't know. If you know please post it as answer. I'll accept.

Comment: I'm voting to close this based on the [OP's comment regarding a duplicate IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203367/cannot-ping-my-computer-on-local-network#comment342599_203465)

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the firewall rejecting ICMP traffic. To test the hypothesis turn off the firewall in yast and try again.

Comment: I found that my ip-address is `192.168.1.4` on both routers. On tp-link router, I have another router with the ip address `192.168.1.4` in the bridge mode. That was causing the problem.

Comment: @Trevor: The question says, "My firewall is disabled."

Comment: @G-Man true. I missed it.